# set tr background for td values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table id="tab" border=2>
    <tr> <td>1</td><td>a</td><td>red</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>2</td><td>a</td><td>green</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>3</td><td>a</td><td>orange</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>4</td><td>a</td><td>green</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>5</td><td>a</td><td>yellow</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>6</td><td>a</td><td>blue</td> </tr>
</table>
```

i can't modify html. i can use only jquery and css. i would like make:
if td == red then all TR with this TD is red, if td == green then all TR is green.
how can i make this?

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/sjuKa/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.text()` to get the text value of a cell, and `.parent()` to get the element's parent. Combining these, you can loop the `td` tags, check if they contain 'red', and if so, get their `.parent()` and set its background-color to red.

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjuKa/2/ for a working example :)

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#tab tr').each(function() {
    $(this).css({'background': $(this).children('td:last').text() });
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/simoncereska/sjuKa/3/

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
var tds = $('td');
tds.each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass( $(this).html().trim() );
})
```

CSS

```
.red
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPwKW/)

Same for all the rest - meaning CSS classes named: orange, green etc.

Comment: Best answer I think. Doing it this way means you can adjust text color for readability, adjust tone of the color, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps even better would be to use text() instead of html() but I don't think it matters much.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('table tr').each(function(){
         if($(this).children(':last').text() == 'red') {
            $(this).children('td').css('background-color', 'red');
         }
      })
   })
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sjuKa/1/